# HTML/CSS Dropdown navigation menu not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown navigation that has a div box absolute which has `visibility:none` but I think when I am hovering, I am not using the correct element. Any help? I think the problem is with the last section of the code. Thanks

[image: When hover 'What's New' area, I would like the redbox to dropdown]

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}

.nav-level-2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: red;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -ms-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    flex: 0px 1px auto;
}

li>a:hover .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <div class="inner max-girdle-width">
    <div class="nav-links-container">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-whats-new"> <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
          <div class="nav-level-2">
            <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
              <div><a href="#">Submenu</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: which div do you want to show after hover the What's new?

Comment: I want .nav-level-2 to show and when i hover over 'What's New', I would like to be able to navigate the redbox( dropdown). Right now the red box closes right away. Help?

Comment: use jquery...hover What's new > mouseenter redbox dropdown > show your item...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `visibility:visible` on hover and add `+` symbol after hover as the sub menu div is outside of the anchor. `li>a:hover .nav-level-2` to `li>a:hover + .nav-level-2`. `+` refers next element of the hovered element.

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}

.nav-level-2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: red;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -ms-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    flex: 0px 1px auto;
}

li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
                        <div class="inner max-girdle-width">
                            <div class="nav-links-container">
                                <ul class="nav-links">
                                    <li class="nav-whats-new">
                                        <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
                                        <div class="nav-level-2">
                                            <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
                                                <div><a href="#">Submenu</a>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </nav>
```

Comment: What if i want the red box (drop down) to stay when i hover 'What's New'?

Comment: I want .nav-level-2 to show and when i hover over 'What's New', I would like to be able to navigate the redbox( dropdown). So I would like the redbox to remain open and be able to click submenu

Comment: in that case you need to change the HTML structure. The `.nav-level-2` div should be in `a` tag and change `li>a:hover + .nav-level-2` to `li>a:hover .nav-level-2`.

Answer (score 0):

The selector at the end is incorrect. What you have specified selects all elements with the class 'nav-level-2' inside the anchor tag on hover. You need to select the div placed immediately after the anchor tag with the '+' selector. And also make the div visible.

To do that try changing the css code at the end to -

```
li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

EDIT :

To keep the menu open when moving the mouse pointer into it, you need to give the hover selector to the container div.

I have changed the last bit of the css to select the 'li' element with the class 'nav-whats-new' and I have used the hover selector on it to change the visibility of the 'nav-level-2' element -

```
li.nav-whats-new:hover .nav-level-2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/hbbaq9tf/3/

Comment: What if i want the red box (drop down) to stay when i hover 'What's New'?

Comment: I want .nav-level-2 to show and when i hover over 'What's New', I would like to be able to navigate the redbox( dropdown). So I would like the redbox to remain open and be able to click submenu

Comment: Hey @echang. I have edited the answer to include that.